# How to update a column with a "blank" value

Tags: sql, sql-update

How do I update a column value (`varchar(20), not null`) with a "blank" value?

Comment: tried what and which database?

Comment: [how-to-empty-a-column-in-mysql](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54111/how-to-empty-a-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to update it with `NULL` you will need to change it to allow `NULL`. Otherwise update with an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 6):

```
Update TableName Set ColumnName='' where [Condtion] // To update column with an enpty values
```

Answer (score 0):

If there have any int column which you may want to do null

`Update TABLE_NAME set name = '',id = cast(NULLIF(id,'') as NVARCHAR)`

Comment: from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6054382/1358091), null is int by default so you don't need to cast