# NULL value for int in Update statement

Tags: sql, sql-update

Is it possible to set NULL value for int column in update statement?

How can I write the update statement in this case?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming the column is set to support NULL as a value:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET column = NULL
```

Be aware of the database NULL handling - by default in SQL Server, NULL is an INT.  So if the column is a different data type you need to CAST/CONVERT NULL to the proper data type:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET column = CAST(NULL AS DATETIME)
```

...assuming `column` is a DATETIME data type in the example above.

Comment: _by default in SQL Server, NULL is an INT_  That is not true and I doubt it ever was even way back in 2011.

Answer (score 7):

By using `NULL`  without any quotes.

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `fieldName` = NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided that your int column is nullable, you may write:

```
UPDATE dbo.TableName
SET TableName.IntColumn = NULL
WHERE <condition>
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is nullable int field then yes.

```
update TableName
set FiledName = null
where Id = SomeId
```