# How to set NCHAR to null with an update statement (C# sqlcommand)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I'm wondering how to set an `nchar` column to null with an update statement. I found this: [NULL value for int in Update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054368/null-value-for-int-in-update-statement)

which says you have to cast to set non-int fields to `NULL`.

So I tried the following:

```
commandText = 
  @"UPDATE Brukere 
      SET Engangskode = CAST(NULL AS NCHAR) 
    WHERE Navn = @navn AND Mobilnr = @mobilnr";
```

However, when I execute this it still won't update the column to `NULL`. Am I casting wrong, or is it something else? Any help would be appreciated :)

Longer code snip if needed: http://pastebin.com/8auKuk6Q

Comment: No need for any casts - just use `UPDATE Brukere SET Engangskode = NULL WHERE Navn = @navn AND Mobilnr = @mobilnr`. That should work **just fine** if the column actually allows `NULL` ...

Comment: @marc_s
See reply to Mihai below. Also not sure why you edited that. I get that you prefer that formatting, but it's not the format of my original code.

Comment: The answer that says _by default in SQL Server, NULL is an INT_ is incorrect.

Comment: And what happens if you use `= NULL` directly? Do you get an error - if so **what** error??

Comment: @juharr
Thanks for the heads up. Weird that it's lying around as the accepted answer with loads of upvotes, then. But I've tried without casting, as mentioned in my comment bellow to mihai.

Comment: From your Pastebin code, I believe your C# code is just wrong - not the SQL ....

Comment: @marc_s
No error (if you look at my original code, I've set a breakpoint in the catch block just so I always get a break if an error has occured). The table just isn't updated with the field set to NULL.

Comment: @marc_s
Well the C# throws no errors either.

Comment: You're not setting the `command.CommandText` to the update statement.  Changing the `commandText` local variable doesn't change the `command.CommandText`.

Comment: @juharr
Oh. Thanks a bunch! Assumed the set commandtext was by reference, not copy. Set it up as an answer and I'll accept it (should probably include that it's because it's not by reference, for future question visitors).

Comment: @user2875994 It is a reference, but you are changing the local variable to reference a new value and that doesn't change any other references.  Also as marc_s says it would be better to just create a separate `SQLCommand`.

Comment: @juharr Ah, I see. Still learning :)

Comment: Also it's generally considered best practice on SO to post your code vs posting a link to it.

Comment: @juharr
I'll keep that in mind. I just assumed it would be a bit "spammy", and pastebin is a pretty neutral site.

Comment: I'd say that's OK if there's a lot of code and you only post the relevant parts in the question and a link to the complete code.

Comment: @juharr
That's kinda what I tried to do. I assumed the rest of the code wasn't directly relevant, but I included it in case it turned out to be so you didn't have to ask me to post it (which turned out to be the case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the local variable `commandText` to the update statement instead of the `command.CommandText`.  Change it to the following

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Brukere SET Engangskode=NULL WHERE Navn=@navn AND Mobilnr=@mobilnr";
```

And I think it will work with or without the casting.

Comment: I simply did this after changing the string:
    `command.CommandText = commandText;` As mentioned above, I thought it was by reference, not by value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Scratch the reference bit.

Comment: It is by reference.  You are setting the reference of `commandText` to a new `string`.  That doesn't effect any other references.  And because `string` is immutable you cannot change the object that they are both referencing either.

Comment: Yeah I understand, read your reply above. I was under the impression that if you changed the value of a variable, you changed it in the same memory location (so all references to it would see the updated value). I guess the case is that you create a new value at a new memory location and change the reference to it, thus not updating other references.

Comment: Yes, strings are kinda special in that a string literal creates a new object without using the `new` keyword and a ctor.

Comment: Aaahhh, I see. So would my past interpretation be correct for other datatypes. Say if it was an int?

Comment: Well `int` is a value type, so no.  You might want to read up on reference types and values types in C#.  http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

Comment: Just a few questions to see if I understood this correctly, I hope you don't mind. 1) You can't pass a reference to a value type (hence why you say it doesn't work for int). You'd have to wrap it in a class then pass it if you wanted to pass it by reference. Correct? 2) For example: I make an object myself storing a string. This is then sent by reference to something else. If I then directly change the string in the object, would the reference sent to "something else" also point to the updated object, or a copy of it containing the old string?

Comment: It might be better if you just ask a new question rather than continuing this in the comments.

Comment: I guess I'll just test it then. Just thought I could get a quick answer while I had your attention, hehe. Well, have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend **NOT** to "re-use" the `SqlCommand` in your example - create a new, specific command for the `UPDATE` statement, something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    string bruker = Request.Cookies["Navn"].Value;
    string mobilnr = Request.Cookies["Mobilnr"].Value;

    string commandText = "SELECT Engangskode FROM Brukere WHERE Navn=@navn AND Mobilnr=@mobilnr";

    bool correctCode = false;

    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
        {
            .....

            if (correctCode)
            {
                // DO NOT "reuse" the previous SqlCommand - create a new, specific one!
                string updateQuery = "UPDATE Brukere SET Engangskode = NULL WHERE Navn = @navn AND Mobilnr = @mobilnr;";

                using (SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, con)
                {
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@navn", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = bruker;
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@mobilnr", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).Value = mobilnr;

                    updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Response.Redirect("Kvittering.aspx",  false);
                }
            }
        }                                    
    }
    catch( .... )
    {
        .......
    }
}
```

Comment: Reusing it works fine. See my reply to Juharr above :) Have an upvote, though.

Answer (score 0):

No need to cast. Juse set column = null. NO quotes, tho!

Comment: No casting results in the same thing, sadly. That's what I tried initially. I guess I should've mentioned.

Comment: Then either the where is filtering out all the rows or the column definition doesn't allow nulls.

Comment: If you look at the larger code snippet, I'm using the exact same WHERE search earlier in the code, and there it finds the correct row. So the filtering should be correct. And the column does allow NULLs